# $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ is rational iff the polynomial $x^3 +Ax + B$ has multiple roots

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Show that the curve of order $3$ given by the equation $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ is rational iff the polynomial $x^3 +Ax + B$ has multiple roots (the characteristic of the ground field is not equal to $2$).

Suppose the curve $f(x, y) = y^2 - x^3 - Ax - B$ was rational, that is, there are rational functions $x = \phi(t), y = \psi(t)$ such that $f(\phi(t), \psi(t)) = 0$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: What does it mean that the curve is rational?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779588/if-the-cubic-polynomial-with-rational-coefficients-x3ax2bxc-has-a-double

Comment: Maybe the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127469/parameterizing-a-rational-curve will show you a procedure.

Comment: A good answer depends on how much algebraic geometry you know. Adding that information to your post would also help with the issue that your post is rather light on context: it's not much more than just the statement of the problem, which is frowned upon around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $y^2=x^3+ax+b=(x-r)^2(x-s)$. Some algebra shows that $r=-{3b\over2a}$ and $s={3b\over a}$. Now one can verify the rational parametrization $x=t^2+s$, $y=(t^2+s-r)t$. So, if the polynomial has a double root, then the curve has a rational parametrization.

Conversely, suppose $\psi(t)^2=\phi(t)^3+a\phi(t)+b$ identically, for some rational functions $\psi,\phi$. Let $\psi(t_0)=0$. Then $g(x)=x^3+ax+b$ vanishes at $x=\phi(t_0)$, and, differentiating with respect to $t$, $g'(x)=(3x^2+a)\phi'(t)=2\psi(t)\psi'(t)$ also vanishes at $t=t_0$, so $g$ has a repeated root.